# uncaught rangeerror: maximum call stack size exceeded: p:inputTextArea and counter attribute

Tags: google-chrome, primefaces, textarea

For one of our web application we are facing a "Unresponsive page" in Chrome. We inspected in chrome development tool, and got "uncaught rangeerror: maximum call stack size exceeded". We have two instance running for same application in two entirely different server. This issue we are facing only in a particular machine and for a particular server for a particular browser (Chrome). It is working fine for others.

The issue is happening for a textarea where we are running a counter to display how many characters remaining from max length. We used primefaces to develop the application. And the issue is appearing in  component where we are using counter and counterTemplate attribute to display how many characters are remaining from max length. And this text area is accepting more than 30000 characters. 
Any insight in this issue is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Chrome Version: Version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Regards
Koushik

Comment: Check all your browser plugins and disable them and try again. And **ALWAYS, ALWAYS, ALWAYS** provide version info. Try other versions of the same browser etc...

Comment: Thanks for your input: Chrome version is Version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Please provide your exact code so we can see it.

Comment: The following primefaces component we have used.
<p:inputTextarea id="commentId"
          value="#{managedBean.pojo.commentProperty}"
          styleClass="Wid95" counter="commentPropertyCharLength" maxlength="30000"
          counterTemplate="{0} characters remaining." />
         <h:outputText id="commentPropertyCharLength" styleClass="Red" />

Once we keep one typing in the field continuously. The error occurs.